# Magento CDN setup, how to update content?

Tags: php, magento, web, cdn

I have a Magento website setup. And I want to setup cdn for it.

So after I setup cdn the URL becomes the cdn url. For example: www.cdn.xxx.com/media

Then lets say I want to update a product on the Magento site. it is going to redirect to www.cdn.xxx.com/media to look for updates.

How do I grab the content from www.mysite.com/media after I update to cdn url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two methods which you can use with a CDN.

**Pull**

With a pull CDN, you keep all the images, etc on your local server, where Magento is installed. Then, when an image is requested the CDN grabs it from your server and caches it (ready for the next request). You can then force the CDN to clear it's cache when you do large changes. This method can cause the initial load to be slow, as the CDN will need to request the file from your server first, save it on the CDN and then serve it to the visitor. This is often the cheaper method and it's the easiest to setup.

**Push**

With a push zone, you will be uploading your files (images, css, js, etc) directly to the CDN, because of this method you will usually be charged for the storage which you use. This allows you to control the content which is pushed to the CDN and update it by pushing the new file(s).

With Magento I always tend to use a Pull CDN (I've used MaxCDN before) as all you need to do is change the URL in the admin, the CDN then takes care of the rest. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods as mentioned: Push or pull. 
I recommend using a pull zone, your content will be fetched automatically from your origin server. There's no need to sync the content over to the CDN (which would be the case for a push zone). The first request to this new file with the CDN URL can indeed be a little bit slower, as the content is not yet cached. But this will be no issue.

> "it is going to redirect to www.cdn.xxx.com/media to look for updates."

No. Small but important detail: The CDN will not redirect (e.g. HTTP 301) requests. The CDN will directly fetch the content and deliver it to the client. The request will then look like this:

```
Client <--> CDN <--> Origin server
```